# TimeCircle - won't update to the new value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery TimeCircles [TimeCircle github](https://github.com/wimbarelds/TimeCircles) and I'm trying to do two things and not sure if I'm going the right way about it.  First off, I'm trying to dynamically set the count down value after creating an instance of TimeCircle.  I understand that upon start up, it looks for data-timer attr in the tag.  However, I'm trying to update that value dynamically. I have a setTimer that calls a method which makes an ajax call to a service which return the number of minutes that TimeCircle should count down from (the 'd' parameter below).  I confirmed that I am getting a value from that service call.  But I was unable to "refresh" TimeCircle with that value. Do I need to destroy it and rebuild the instance to refresh? Any help is appreciated fellows!

Second, I'm trying to show the days and hours circles dynamically depending on whether or not I have  "zero" for day and/or hour.  In other words, if day or hour is zero, there is no reason to show the circle(s).  Strike two - wasn't successful with that either.

Thanks in advance for any help and to the author of TimeCircles (good stuff!).

```
function doCircleTimer(d) {

var dd = d;
if (dd == undefined) {
    dd = $('div#CountDownTimer', window.parent.document).data('timer');
}
var _timer = $('div#CountDownTimer', window.parent.document);

_timer = $('div#CountDownTimer', window.parent.document).attr('data-timer', dd);


_timer.TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show: true }, Hours: { show: true }, Minutes: { color: '#4D8DC1' }, Seconds: { color: '#4D8DC1'}} })
.addListener(
function (unit, value, total) {
    //hide days
    if (total < 86400) {
        _timer.TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show: false }, Hours: { show: true,  color: '#900' }, Minutes: { color: '#900' }, Seconds: { color: '#900'}} })

    }
     if (total < 3600) {

        _timer.TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show: false, color: '#900' }, Hours: { show: false, color: '#900' }, Minutes: { color: '#900' }, Seconds: { color: '#900'}} })
    } 
    if (total == 120) {
        _timer.data('timer', 120);
        alert("Two-Minute Warning!");
        _timer.TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show: false }, Hours: { show: false }, Minutes: { color: '#900' }, Seconds: { color: '#900'}} })
    } else if (total == 30) {
        alert('Your session will expire in 30 seconds, you should save your work and / or  reload the page.');
    } else if (total == 0) {

        alert("Time Expired");

    }
}
);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the creator of TimeCircles.

The first thing I've noticed that's wrong here is that, in order to remove a circle while running, you need to call `.rebuild()`.

Also, you're re-setting the config every single second this way due to using the < operator.
Something else: you seem to be setting the time to 120 when it hits 120, I don't understand what you're trying to do there.

Finally, you seem to be using a mix of `.data()` and `.attr('data'..`. What you should realize is that, changing `.data` doesn't effect `.attr`, and `.attr` doesn't effect `.data`.

Now, if I understand you correctly- this function is called after TimeCircles is already instantiated. In that case, I would recommend something like this:

```
        var listenerAdded = false;

        function listener(unit, value, total) {
            if(total === 86399 || total === 3599) {
                $(this).TimeCircles().destroy();
                $(this).data('timer', total + 1).TimeCircles(getConfig(total));
            }
            if(total == 120) {
                alert("Two-Minute Warning!");
            }
            else if(total == 30) {
                alert('Your session will expire in 30 seconds, you should save your work and / or  reload the page.');
            }
            else if(total == 0) {
                alert("Time Expired");
            }
        }

        function getConfig(seconds) {
            var config = { time: {
                Days: { show: true },
                Hours: { show: true },
                Minutes: { show: true, color: '#4D8DC1' },
                Seconds: { show: true, color: '#4D8DC1' },
            }};
            if(seconds <= 86400) {
                config.time.Days.show = false;
                config.time.Seconds.color = "#900";
                config.time.Minutes.color = "#900";
                if(seconds <= 3600) {
                    config.time.Hours.show = false;
                }
                else {
                    config.time.Hours.color = "#900";
                }
            }
            return config;
        }

        function doCircleTimer(d) {

            var $timer = $('div#CountDownTimer', window.parent.document);
            var dd = d;
            if (dd == undefined) {
                dd = $timer.data('timer');
            }

            $timer.data('timer', dd);
            var tc = $timer.TimeCircles(getConfig(dd)).rebuild().restart();
            if(!listenerAdded)
                tc.addListener(listener);
        }
```

Comment: First off, thank you for looking into it.  Second, I copied and pasted the two functions.  If I give it say 3500 seconds to countdown, `(total === 3600)` is never called and therefore days and hours are still shown.  Do you agree?  In other words, if it's 1:01 two seconds later (at 0:59) the day and hour circles are gone when it passes 3600 seconds.  But if you refresh the page, they come back since it's passed 3600.  Sadly, the refresh countdown didn't work either for me.  I placed the .rebuild in various places but to no avail. Where do you suggest that I rebuild the timer? Thanks again

Comment: I'm at work now and can't really test anything, but you're right about the first bit.  I forgot to also use the get configurations the first time. If you do, then whenever the Ajax call happens it will show the right circles. Ill have more time to look at this in a few hours

Comment: Something else I noticed was that every time you call `doCircleTimer()`, it adds another listener. That's not good. I tried to fix the script- but it looks like there's a few annoying bugs that I need to work out. I did update my post above with a script that will work-- but `.destroy()` shouldn't have been needed.  Either way, it works!

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this.  I like your work.  Is there a group that I can join so I can keep up with your dev?

Comment: Your best chance would be to follow me on github, though at the moment TimeCircles is my only notable project. I did start something new a few days ago, but that will take quite a while before it becomes anything.